# Trouble with A Java Merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am having trouble with this merge sort algorithm. I have 3 total methods to do a merge sort, plus the main method calling it. It is not outputting a sorted array and I am not sure where I went wrong. It all looks right to me when I am looking at it, I am not sure if the error is within the recursive parts of the method, or if it's within just one of the classes. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
Here is my code:

```
/**
 * To do: Implement merge sort.
 * @param array the array to sort
 * @return the sorted array
 */
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] array) {
    // call mergeSort(int [], int, int) to initiate sorting
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
    return mergeSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
}

/**
 * To do: Implement overloaded merge sort method.
 * @param array the array to sort
 * @param begin the starting index of the array to be sorted
 * @param end the last index of the array to be sorted
 */
private static int[] mergeSort(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
    // you need to write the merge sort algorithm here
    // use this method mergeSort(int [], int, int) and merge(int [], int[])
    // to complete it
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();


    if(begin < end) {
        int [] left = new int[array.length/2];
        int [] right = new int[array.length - left.length];

        //copies first half of array into left
        for(int i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }
        //copies second half into right array
        for(int j = 0; j < right.length; j++) {
            right[j] = array[left.length + j];
        }

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        return merge(left, right);
    }
    return array;
}


/**
 * To do: Merge two sorted arrays into one and return it
 * @param left the first array
 * @param right the second array
 * @return the sorted merged array
 */
private static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
    // merge two sorted array such way that it remains sorted
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    int [] sorted = new int[left.length + right.length];

    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < sorted.length; j++ ) {
        if( leftIndex <= left.length-1 && rightIndex <= right.length-1) {

            if(left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex]) {
                sorted[j] = left[leftIndex];
                leftIndex++;
            }
            else {
                sorted[j] = right[rightIndex];
                rightIndex++;
            }
        }
        else if( leftIndex < left.length) {
            sorted[j] = left[leftIndex];
            leftIndex++;
        }
        else if(rightIndex< right.length) {
            sorted[j] = right[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried debugging it?

Comment: plz check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mergeSort` function is not in-place, i.e. it returns a new array instead of changing the order of elements in the same array. Therefore, these 2 lines:

```
            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);
```

will have absolutely no effects.

Change it to:

```
            left = mergeSort(left);
            right = mergeSort(right);
```

Another comment: Even though your merge sort is `O(NlogN)`, you use a lot copying arrays around, which creates a lot of the overhead. Try to use in place operation as much as possible, avoid creating extra array. Most often, the merge sort uses no more than 2 arrays at any time.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much. I spent hours trying to figure out what was up, thanks for showing me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think we're in the same class. You have to use the "begin" and "end" values to create a sub-array from the original array parameter. After that you can separate it into "right" and "left", similar to what you have done already.

As for the the merge() method I would recommend looking at the code in the textbook. The only difference between the code in the book and our assignment is that we have to create a result array inside the method:

```
int[] array = new int[left.length-right.length];
```

and then return it when it's done. Hope that helped.